# windows xp to windows 7 file transfer via USB and via command line

Tags: p2p, rndis

I have a windows XP based computer that is connected (peer 2 peer style) to a Windows 7 based computer. The goal is file transfer between the two.

Here's hitch one, the connection between the two computers is via USB.  Ethernet is not an option and completely off the table for this situation, we're stuck with USB (Windows XP computer hardware configuration is inaccessible save for the USB hub).  We do have the ability to install software on it though.....same situation goes for the Windows 7 machine

Here's hitch two, The solution MUST be implemented such that file transfers can be accomplished via DOS command terminal from the Windows XP based computer...so no bridge cable and "GUI dragging of files" is allowed.  A bridge cable driven by DOS command line..now that would be a solution but have yet to see one.

Here's some buzzwords I have accumulated through some lengthy google research that might help explain where I believe I'm heading.

- usbnet
- RNDIS
- PuTTY
- plink
- FTP server

I would like to ask how the IT experts would handle this, what software is needed on which end and what kind of configurations could I expect to have to deal with.  I am a bit unsure about the whole ethernet over USB thing as it applies to this peer 2 peer situation and would welcome any advice.